# Certain applications appearing as black icons

Tags: windows-10, icons

Taskbar icons appearing like this:

[image]

Microsoft Word, Excel and Outlook icons appear as blank icons on the taskbar. Also, no longer offering the option to Pin/Unpin from the taskbar.

Comment: Did anything get changed just before it went wrong, such as a Windows update or a change of the graphics card?

Comment: @AndrewMorton No, and the issue is only occuring with these specific Microsoft applications, e.g. OneNote is working perfectly fine.

Comment: In that case, perhaps a repair of Office is needed. You didn't mention which versions of Windows 10 and Office you're using (they moved things around in some version of W10), but I expect you can find out how to do that.